# In present perfect, can you use a phrase to describe condition after "since"?

Tags: present-perfect

I have a question about a phrase that comes after "since" when you use present perfect tense.

When you joined a local sports club and got to know someone years ago, and neither you nor that person belongs to the club now but you see each other sometimes, can you say this sentence?

> I have known her since we were in the club.

I am not sure if this sentence is appropriate because I suspect that something describing a point in time has to come after "since" (like "since I joined the club"), not a condition that was present over a period of time (like "since we were in the club").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an American, this sentence is fine if that event (being in the club) is no longer ongoing. For example, you can say you can say "I have known her since we were in primary school" as long as you are no longer in primary school, even though the event (being in primary school) happened over a period of time, not a single point.

### Bonus Information

If the event that you list here *is* ongoing, it changes the meaning of the word since to be "because." For example, the sentence "I know her since we are in the club together." means that you know each other because you participate in the same club.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite appropriate, not for the reason you think but because *in the club* is used as a British slang expression for *pregnant!*

However, you can perfectly well say something like "I've known her since we both belonged to the tennis club" - or "used to belong".

Comment: Fascinating! That's a piece of British slang I haven't heard of before! How do students typically refer to activities they participate in? In the US, you might here a student say "oh yeah, they talked about that at the club meeting" or "I have a club now" to talk about any sort of arts, sports, theater, politics, etc. student organizations.

Comment: @Griffin I didn't say you couldn't _mention_ clubs, just that the particular expression 'in the club' is liable to raise a few giggles in the UK.

Comment: @KateBunting: ***She*** might have been "in the club"=pregnant, but not ***we***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They could both have been expecting at the same time!

Comment: @Griffin, the longer form of the expression is "in the pudding club".

Comment: @KateBunting: In retrospect I can't believe it never occurred to me that *both* of two people who met at a sports club might be women! I obviously just don't have the right attitude here! :(

Answer (score 0):

OP's example usage is fine. But it's worth pointing out that there's an interesting ambiguity concerning ***since*** in the cited context...

> 1: *I have **known** him since we were at university*
> 2: *I have **seen** him since we were at university*

Pragmatically, we would normally assume ***since*** in #1 refers to *when I **started** at university* (probably that's when I first met him, so I knew him ***while*** we were students). But ***since*** in #2 refers to ***after I left** university*.